# Java Comparing an array list's specific objects values

Tags: java, arraylist, compare, knn

I'm doing a KNN Project. I have an arraylist that stores objects that have 4 attributes(int,int,double,string) How do I get to each specific string and compare them with another string( it won't let me use contain function which I need). The thing is that my sortedEuclid arraylist has 14 members, but the other arraylists have different members, classYesMembers(only has Yes's in it) has 9 and classNoMembers(only has No's in it) has 5 members. Here is my code, thank you very much in advance. convk is the size that the user enters to display the first lowest elements until the highest in ascending order. For example, if the user enters 3, it will display the lowest 3 euclidean distances, and will link yes or no based on those distances.

```
for(int i=0; int i< convk; i++){

  if(sortedEuclid.get(i).getClasses().equals(classYesMembers)){
    classYesCount++;
  }else{
    classNoCount++;
  }
}
```

Comment: So very **DO NOT** understand your purpose here ~ (downvoted **not** from me). Would you please elaborate and format your question better?

Comment: This won't compile. Your braces are unbalanced.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to sort your stuff out.

You have a class like

```
class MyObject {
    … some fields
    String string;
    … some more fields
}
```

and you have a `List<MyObject> sortedEuclid`.

Furthermore you have two `List<String> classYesMembers` and `classNoMembers`.

`convk` seems to be the `size()` of your `sortedEuclid`?

Then I'd do it this way:

```
for(MyObject o : sortedEuclid) {
    if (classYesMembers.contains(o.string)) {
       classYesCount++;
    }
    if (classNoMembers.contains(o.string)) {
       classNoCount++;
    }
}
```

There is potential to further improvement, but let's first check if I am on the right track.

Comment: I edited the question. I want the for loop to check whether the sortedEuclid contains "yes" or "no" . sortedEuclid is an arraylist that has 4 variables, int xarray, int yarray, double euclid, string classes . I've already sorted the euclid values in ascending order using a hashmap now I want to know whether or not there is a yes or a no corresponding to that euclid using a for loop. it is a KNN project, sorry for the misunderstanding